# How can I add Wordpress php code into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the following javascript code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','assets/images/logo.png'); //change src
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','assets/images/logo__footer.png')

    }
});
```

Is it possible to insert a wp custom php code

```
<?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
```

Instead of this static attribute

```
.attr('src','assets/images/logo.png');
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this javascript created as part of a php script or is it in a `.js` file that you link in to the page

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hey, it's a part of js file

Comment: Then I think the amsnwer is no, not directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set variable in template:

```
<script>
    var logoImage = <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>;
    var logoImageFooter = <?php the_custom_logo()?> //here footer logo
</script>
```

and than, in your js file use it

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',logoImage); //change src
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',logoImageFooter)

    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @vasyl-zhuryk , thank you so much. Could you, please, let me know in what exact template I have to set variable?

Comment: @Jamdev Now, I don't have wordpress server, and can't see the file. But you can find it by yourself. html file in your module, which is loading with your js file

Comment: Much appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Your Js code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 50)  /*height in pixels when the navbar becomes non opaque*/ 
    {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','custom_logo.png'); //change src
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('sticky');
        $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src','logo_footer.png')

    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<?php $customLogo= 'custom_logo'; ?>
<?php $footerLogo= 'footer_logo'; ?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      // notice the quotes around the ?php tag         
      var customLogo="<?php echo $customLogo; ?>";
      var footerLogo="<?php echo $footLogo; ?>";
      alert(customLogo);
      alert(footerLogo);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you need jquery with php code input then `wp_localize_script()` function.
[More information](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

```
 var logoImage = <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>;
var logoImageFooter = <?php the_custom_logo()?> //here footer logo

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'logo_image' => the_custom_logo(),
    'logo_image_footer' => the_custom_logo()'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

**You can access the variables in JavaScript as follows:**

```
    <script>
        alert( object_name.logo_image);
        alert( object_name.logo_image_footer);
    </script> 


 $('.navbar-brand img').attr('src',object_name.logo_image); //change src
```